# Black background when turning a PNG into a GIF

Tags: php

I have a PNG image I am trying to open and then output as a GIF image. However, the transparency is lost when I do this and the background turns black. If I output the image as a PNG, it works, but I specifically need to open the image as a PNG and the output it as a GIF.

This is what I have so far:

```
 <?php
 header("Content-type: image/gif");

 $new_img = imagecreatefrompng($image);
 imagealphablending($new_img, false); 
 imagesavealpha($new_img, true); 
 imagegif($new_img);
 ?>
```

However, imagepng($new_img) saves the background transparency but does not output as a GIF.

Comment: Oh if I create the image as a gif in the first place and do this, it works fine. So it's not my browser. It's the transition from PNG to GIF that messes it up.

Comment: @sombe - "Most major browsers don't support transparency in gifs", I think all browsers since 1800 have supported transparency in GIFs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to get this to work. Please let me know if anyone has a better solution:

```
 <?php
  header("Content-type: image/gif");

  $new_img = imagecreatefrompng($image);
  $background = imagecreatefrompng("background.png");
  imagecopyresampled($background, $new_img, 0, 12, 0, 0, 100, 125, 100, 125);
  $c = imagecolorat($background, 0, 0);
  imagefilledrectangle($background, 0, 112, 100, 125, $c);
  imagecolortransparent($background, $c);
  imagegif($new_img);
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/gif");

$new_img = imagecreatefrompng($image);
$trans_color = imagecolortransparent($new_img);
$trans_index = imagecolorallocate($new_img, $trans_color['red'], $trans_color['green'], $trans_color['blue']);
imagecolortransparent($new_img, $trans_index);
imagegif($new_img);
?>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working either. The main problem is the transition from PNG to GIF, I think, so maybe if there were a way to change the image into a GIF and then mess with the transparency before outputting the whole thing to the browser.